# Using drupal_render() for Simplenews checkbox disables username and password fields

Tags: forms, users, emails

I have a custom user-register.tpl.php file in which I have:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['simplenews']); ?>
```

along side several other renders, and when this specific one is active, the following renders: name, mail and password, do not output, which makes my user register page useless.

Anyone knows why and if there is someway I can avoid this? I have installed (but disabled) [LoginTobbogan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), since I thought these two modules didn't get along, but now I find this behaviour being [Simplenews](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews)' only.

My goal here is to provde a checkbox so users who are registering can opt to subscribe or not to the newsletter. I've already seen the Simplenews' action trigger in which users would be subscribed automatically, without their consent, and this is not what I want particularly.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing drupal render on the whole form.